# PHP include outside url

Tags: url, include, mediawiki

When trying to include a php file into another it either does nothing at all (no errors). If i require it will give a useless message

```
"Failed opening required 'http://example.org.com/xxx.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php')

<div id="menu"> <?php include("http://www.sitename.com/menu.php") ?> </div>
```

The file im trying to include is on the same site and host. 
The page im including from is:

```
root/wiki/skin/index.php (mediawiki)
```

menu.php is located:

```
root/menu.php
```

since mediawiki treats the /wiki/ path as the root i cannot back out with ../../ etc.

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you misconfigured your short URL. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Answer (score 0):

Sir, try this:

```
<div id="menu"> <?php include("../../menu.php") ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To include URLs in your PHP project you must have enabled (true) this option:

**allow_url_include**

in your **php.ini** configuration. More information you can find here:
http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include